# Character count using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I count the number of characters in a textbox using jQuery?

```
$("#id").val().length < 3
```

just counts upto 3 character spaces but not the number of characters.

Comment: `$("#id").val().length` returns the number of characters in a string.  What's the problem?

Comment: What does "just counts upto 3 character spaces but not the number of characters" mean?

Comment: I need to count the number of characters excluding the spaces, a trim function of the sort jquery.trim() ?

Comment: I am using `$("#id").val().length` and when I use `.html()` to print it out it stays as 0.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**For length including white-space:**

`$("#id").val().length`

**For length without white-space:**

```
$("#id").val().replace(/ /g,'').length
```

**For removing only beginning and trailing white-space:**

```
$.trim($("#test").val()).length
```

For example, the string `" t e s t "` would evaluate as:

```
//" t e s t "
$("#id").val(); 

//Example 1
$("#id").val().length; //Returns 9
//Example 2
$("#id").val().replace(/ /g,'').length; //Returns 4
//Example 3
$.trim($("#test").val()).length; //Returns 7
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cEbdD/1) is a demo using all of them.

Comment: That regular expression will do what you need.

Comment: @RionWilliams, i used your fiddle and tweaked it a bit, but it's not working. it's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/juhbr43m/). any ideas?

Comment: @yak613 It doesn't look like the code that you provided does anything. It will display a count when the page is first loaded, but nothing much after that. If you wanted to display the count as you typed, you could attach an event handler to the keypress, keyup or keydown events similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/juhbr43m/3/) or if you just wanted to calculate it on the button click, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/juhbr43m/5/) should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.length` to count number of characters, and `$.trim()` function to remove spaces, and `replace(/ /g,'')` to replace multiple spaces with just one. Here is an example:

```
   var str = "      Hel  lo       ";
   console.log(str.length); 
   console.log($.trim(str).length); 
   console.log(str.replace(/ /g,'').length);
```

Output:

```
20
7
5
```

Source: [How to count number of characters in a string with JQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-count-number-of-characters-in-a-string-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the given answers to this question has worked for me (I ask myself if jQuery has changed in this regard somehow?), I am adding **the solution that does work in my case**, i.e. using `$('#myelement').text().length;` to determine the number of characters inside a tag (defined by tag name or id).

```js
var x = $('h1').text().length;
console.log(x);
$('#solution').text(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>How many characters are in this H1?</h1>
<p>This is just some more text.</p>
<p style="font-size: 1.4em;">Solution: There are <span id="solution"></span> characters in the h1 tag, including spaces</p>
```