# Check length of div excluding spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to detect if there is content within a certain div:

```
if ($(".bio").html().length > 0) {
   $('.author-info').hide();
}
```

The problem I run into is there are cases where a space may be in the `.bio` field. I want to check the length excluding spaces. In other words, check to see if the div has content but spaces do not count as content.

How do I do this?

Note: I am using jQuery 2.1.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [character count using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661481/character-count-using-jquery)

Comment: @apaul34208 - While I can gleam an answer from that question unsure if it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a comment if you downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove all the spaces and check the length of the result:

```
$(".bio").text().replace(/ /g, '').length > 0
```

We could also be more general and select all whitespace with `\s`:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".bio").each(function(){
    if( $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length > 0 ){
      $(this).after("<- Has text");
    } else {
      $(this).after("<- Just spaces");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="bio">Text with spaces</span>
<br>
<span class="bio">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if($(".bio").html().trim().length > 0){
    ...
}
```

See [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 1):

You could just add another condition to check if there is space like so:

```
if (($(".bio").html().length > 0)&&($(".bio").text()!=" ")) 
{
   $('.author-info').hide();
}
```

Comment: $(".bio").text()!=" ") will only work if 'bio' element has *exactly* one space in it, so this won't work if there is more than one space.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @abl and @Purag's good answers, you can also manually loop through the text, looking for non-space characters:

```
var bioContent = $(".bio").html();
var hasContent = false;
var characterToIgnore = ' ';

for (var i=0;i<bioContent.length;i++){
    if (bioContent[i] != characterToIgnore){
        hasContent = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h6t4z9j/3/)